# Tomcat 7.0.5 was ever GA?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

In one of the projects I saw we are using Tomcat 7.0.5, I went on the http://tomcat.apache.org/ and clicked on the archives to download the old version (I wanted to have same environment on my local machine),to my surprise I see there is no download link on http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/ for 7.0.5.
On this page I did not see any link which said 7.0.5 but I found one saying v7.0.5-beta but in release notes or licence of v7.0.5 I didn't find beta word.

So I am worndering if 7.0.5 was availed on GA any time? Or 7.0.5 was always beta?

If its beta we may need to switch to newer version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way to find the Tomcat version using any command or looking the content of any file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 7.0.6 was the first stable release :
http://www.mail-archive.com/announce@tomcat.apache.org/msg00034.html